# Powers of positive semidefinite functions

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-transform, positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

A function $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ is *positive semidefinite* if for any $n \geq 1$, any $z_1, \ldots, z_n \in \mathbb C$, and any $x_1, \ldots, x_n$, the inequality holds:
$$
\sum_{k,l = 1}^n z_k \overline z_l f(x_k - x_l) \geq 0.
$$
In other words, the matrix whose entries are $f(x_k - x_l)$ is positive semidefinite for any $n$ and any choice of $x_1, \ldots, x_n$. We'll say $f$ is *Hermitian* if $f(-x) = \overline{f(x)}$ (i.e., the matrix is Hermitian).

**My question:** Suppose $f$ is positive semidefinite, $f(0) =1$, and the range of $f$ is a simply connected region in $\mathbb C$ that does not contain $0$. Given $r>0$, is the exponentiated function $f^r$ also positive semidefinite? What if $f$ is Hermitian? (Here $f^r$ is a continuous branch if $r$ isn't an integer.)

By the spectral theorem for Hermitian operators, the answer is *yes* for positive semidefinite Hermitian matrices (if $A$ is Hermitian positive semidefinite, a unique positive semidefinite $n$th root exists, so by continuity, real exponentiation can be canonically defined). But I'm not sure how to show this for *functions*, as the diagonalization of the matrix $\left(f(x_k - x_l)\right)_{1 \leq k,l \leq n}$ need not be related obviously to the diagonalization of $\left(f(x_k - x_l)^r\right)_{1 \leq k,l \leq n}$.

Any thoughts?

(I included the tag "characteristic functions" because this problem came up for me in the context of trying to use Bochner's theorem to generate a continuous family of probability measures on $\mathbb R$.)

Comment: How is $f^r$ defined?  It's a multi-valued function on $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @JohnDoe fair point. I've edited the problem. I mean for $f^r$ to be a particular continuous branch, single valued.

Comment: @D Ford: Continuous branch of $\log z$ (for $\exp(r \log z)$) can only be defined on a simply connected domain not containing zero - but the values $f$ takes are not constrained to such a domain.

Comment: Again, fair point. I've edited the question. In fact the $f$ that I'm interested in are characteristic functions of probability measures in $\mathbb R$ that are demonstrably not equal to $0$ anywhere.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [Bochner-Herglotz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner%27s_theorem#Special_cases) theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comment about tags suggests using Bochner's theorem to answer your question.  Since the product of characteristic functions is also a characteristic function, $f^r$ is psd if $r$ is a positive integer.  But if $f^r$ is a characteristic function for *all* $r>0$ it must be the case for all $r$ of form $r=1/n$, which makes $f$ an [infinitely divisible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_divisibility_(probability)) characteristic function.

A glance at the Wikipedia article tells you that the uniform distribution is not infinitely divisible, so $f(t)=\sin t / t$ is a counterexample to your inequality in the case $r=1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Under some additional assumptions the answer is yes. If $f$ is down to be the characteristic function of a finite positive measure $\mu$, that is if $f=\widehat{\mu}$, then then $f^n=  \widehat{\mu^{*n}}$ where $\mu^{*n}=\mu*\mu^{*(n-1)}$ (convolution of $mu$ with itself $n$-times. A celebrated [result](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner%27s_theorem) by [Bochner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salomon_Bochner) states

> Theorem: A bounded continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is positive definite iff $f$ is the characteristic function of a finite Borel measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

The conclusion of the OP for  nonnegative intgegrer powers under continuity follows from that theorem.

For fractional powers, one may have to consider [infinite divisible measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_divisibility_(probability)): an infinite divisible probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is a measure such that for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there is another probability measure $\mu_n$ such that $\mu^{*n}_n=\mu$. The extension to real (nonnegative) power then is accomplished via the Lévi-Bochner continuity theorem.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if $f^r$ is positive semidefinite for a *dense* set of $r$, then by continuity, it should be positive semidefinite for *all* $r$ by continuity. This makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Comment: @DFord: No. For all integer $N$ yes as long as $f$is the characteristic function of a finite measure. For characteristic functions of infinite divisible measures you can extend things to rational powers and then to real by Levy-Bochner theorem.That is a big component of what Levy processes are.